# Is there a way for me to simply plot all of these vectors on a single graph?

Tags: r

[these are the vectors that need to all be plotted on the same graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEZiZ.png)

I would like to plot all of these vectors on one set. I've seen methods using matrices but I can't fathom how I would organize this as a matrix and I also would rather work with the vectors. Is there a method I can use to have these all on a single graph?

```
x_axis <- c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7)
mouse_r_veh <- c(6, 7, 5, 2, 3, 7)
mouse_r_cap <- c(27, 22, 21, 25, 21, 25)
mouse_rr_veh <- c(7, 3, 4, 6, 4, 17)
mouse_rr_cap <- c(24, 27, 29, 9, 10, 21)
mouse_l_veh <- c(10, 12, 11, 16, 13, 2)
mouse_l_cap <- c(26, 23, 23, 23, 24, 22)
mouse_ll_veh <- c(0, 2, 1, 3, 0, 0)
```

Comment: can you explain exactly what output you want?

Comment: A single graph with 7 different plots, each plot representing the data from a specific vector.

Comment: Do you want 7 different coordinate systems each containing one line or seven lines in one coordinate system as @Waldi has in his answer? Do you want a base graphic or a ggplot2 graphic?

Answer (score 1):

You could put the data in a `data.frame` and use `pivot_longer` to create a new variable with the name of each serie:

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(x_axis,      
                 mouse_r_veh, 
                 mouse_r_cap, 
                 mouse_rr_veh,
                 mouse_rr_cap,
                 mouse_l_veh, 
                 mouse_l_cap, 
                 mouse_ll_veh)

data <- df %>% pivot_longer(cols = contains('mouse'))

ggplot(data) + geom_line(aes(x = x_axis, y = value, color = name))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use matplot, nor yet ggplot, you could just do a single `plot` call and several `lines`:

```r
plot(x_axis, ylim = c(0, 30))
lines(mouse_r_cap, col="red")
lines(mouse_r_veh, col = "green")
# ... et cetera
```

If you don't mind using matplot with a matrix, you could do:

```r
mx <- cbind(x_axis, mouse_r_veh, mouse_r_cap, 
        mouse_rr_veh, mouse_rr_cap, mouse_l_veh, 
        mouse_l_cap, mouse_ll_veh)
matplot(mx, type ="l")
```